# Electrical Sub-panel feeding out through main panel service line entry

Tags: subpanel

We are running electrical to our shed as an outbuilding. The primary issue is getting the lines back out of the house in a convenient location. My question is whether we can run this sub panel supply out through the main service entrance. We could then tir into the service with conduit and bury it appropriately.

Is this allowed? I can't fine anything specific. We are in Lynnwood, WA in the US.

As requested, here is the external 2" Conduit body that we are considering tying into.

[image]

And the interior of the panel.

[image]

Comment: If you ended up in an outside main disconnect, maybe,,,,, in your meter can, no.  but wait for the experts.

Comment: While you're waiting, pics of all the existing equipment in question would be most helpful. All the labeling on the existing panel, pics of the service entrance and any labeling you can find on panels/boxes there (without cutting the seal on the meter itself). Anything at all that you've looked at will be helpful for people here to see. You can [edit] your question, then just drag pics into the text box for automatic upload & host, or hit the "sun & mountain" icon to include pics. Additionally, code varies by location, so at a minimum, your country. City & state would help too.

Comment: @FreeMan photos added, thank you for the suggestion. Added to the main post as well but we are in Lynnwood, WA in the US.

Comment: No, probably not. You'd be "altering" a UL listed part. Almost certainly not code legal.  Also, putting wires for a sub-panel right next to main feed wires could have unintended induction effects on the sub-panel feed.   Besides that, how to you plan on drilling a hole right next to live, high voltage, very high current conductors? "very carefully" doesn't work here. One nick thru the insulation with the drill bit and you're toast. You'll just need to install another LB with conduit into the house and down into the ground to your outbuilding. ...cont below...

Comment: Also, don't forget about the rules for a sub-panel in an outbuilding:  1)  4 wire feed is required (2 hots, neutral and ground).  2) neutral must be isolated (not bonded) to ground in the sub-panel, 3) you must have 2 ground rods at the outbuilding connected to the ground on the sub-panel.

Comment: Use caution getting assistance from the internet there are two many missings to answer this. Is there a breaker at the meter? What size/ type is the wire coming in? Since the main is 100a the wire could be #2 aluminum , with this size service you have gas or a tiny home in the PNW as this is the minimum service allowed by code. 
With #2 there is room for many more conductors but a derate calculation will be needed will it matter ? If there is a breaker should have been asked first.

Comment: @EdBeal  question:  Where did you determine the mains supplying the house was 100 amps? I thought the shed/outbuilding was going to be fed by 100 amps, which seems like a LOT for a "shed" unless they are planning a "grow" operation or crypto mining rigs.  I do like outdoor disconnects for a couple of reasons:  If a fire, the fire dept can quickly turn off power to the house, second, for people not comfortable working in a live panel for electrical work, it can be turned off completely.

Comment: George the op stated a 100 amp breaker in the text box in the photo. If that is not accurate that information would be needed also but we can see it is copper I missed this at first so if 100a it could be a #4 but as I said not enough info

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### TLDR: Forget it and punch a second conduit through the wall.

Trying to use this conduit would be *onerous* because of the adaptations needed to make that possible.

Note that even in a dedicated pipe, #2 aluminum is only 90A wire and #4 copper is only 85A wire. Lots of people get this wrong (including pros) because they are reading out of the wrong table in NEC.  You use Table 310.16 (aka TAble 310.15(B)(16) to size feeders, using the 60C or 75C column in residential.

### You can't run *service wires* in the same conduit with anything else.

You say these are *service entrance* wires, so they exist from the weatherhead to the meter, and from the meter to the main breaker.  Note that all of this is on the "hot" side of the main breaker and these are energized at all times.  (outside of pulling the meter).

Those can't coexist with feeder (to your subpanel) or branch circuit wires.

### A meter-main or combo panel

Your best solution might be replacing your meter pan with a "Meter-Main".  This is a combination meter-pan + main breaker.  Downstream of the meter-main, those aren't service wires anymore, they are feeder. Feeder can be in the same conduit with feeder + branch circuit wires.

But you might as well take it 1 step further and make that a "combo panel" which includes meter + main + a few breaker spaces, e.g. a "Ranch Panel" is made *specifically* for what you are trying to do: tap off large feeders to subpanels elsewhere.  Now you completely side-step the problem of 2 circuits through a conduit! Just come straight out of the ranch panel to wherever you are going.

Note that #4 copper and #2 aluminum are *not* adequate for 100A subpanel feeder. Many people read this off the wrong chart in NEC.  They are actually 85A and 90A respectively. For 100A you need #3 copper or #1 aluminum. There is nothing wrong with aluminum at these large sizes.

### 2-3 circuits through a conduit need a derate

Anytime you have a conduit 24" or longer, if 2 or more circuits are in it, a "derate" comes off the wire ampacity. You take the highest temperature the wire is rated for, multiply by 0.8 (80%) for 2-3 circuits, and your load can't exceed that. See 310.15(B)(7) which I think just moved to 310.12.

As a result, you would need increase 1 wire size (-1 numerical size) on each wire, including the <del>service</del> main feeder wires.  I'll spare you the number-crunch.  If you go aluminum on the subpanel feeder (and I definitely would), then either the service wires or the feeder will need to be THWN insulation - they won't quite fit if both are XHHW.

### You can't field-modify stuff

Your idea of "adding a fitting" to the LB conduit body is a non-starter.  It violates 110.2, 110.3 and 300.18.

110.2 says you must use UL-Listed equipment, and 110.3 says use it according to its instructions. 300.18 says any time you're dealing with conduit *end to end* as a wiring method, as is required to protect individual THHN or XHHW or RHW conductors like those... you must assemble the conduit complete before adding any wires.    So you would need to pull the wires out *anyway*, and at that point you might as well change that to a proper, pre-made "TEE" conduit body, probably with an LB right after that to turn straight down (or just an adapter and a sweep).

Unfortunately that conduit is PVC, and that stuff is all *glued*, so much of it may be scrap.  Ouch.  Never liked that stuff. Also, if the conduit is not metal, *how do you ground the meter pan?* We see a lot of "lost neutrals" so I wouldn't tie it to neutral. Well, a meter-main would take care of that.

Comment: Another upside to the meter main or ranch panel transition is it meets the recent requirements for an external disconnect.

Comment: great answer, as usual Harp. but a pretty expensive and intrusive install.   Wouldn't just be simpler and easier just to install another LB with appropriate conduit into the house and into the ground for the underground feed to the outbuilding? Maybe have to open up some sheet rock next to the panel, but that's a lot less expensive than going whole hog with a meter main combo with breaker space.   They could simply open up some sheetrock, run the conduit, run the wires, slap in a breaker and their done other than repairing the sheetrock. what am I missing here.

Comment: The external disconnect is only required if the AHJ adopted that section in the 2020, I know oregon did not, but think WA. state did. If there their is a breaker at the meter the op can run back out. 8 conductors depending on the wire rating may not be a problem but as usual a very long explanation, with not enough information from the OP to provide a proper code related answer.

Comment: @EdBeal Interesting, I didn't realize AHJs were overriding NEC with great frequency like that. I'd heard Michigan deleted all the *FCI requirements but I thought that was unusual.  Only makes sense, some of the newer requirements are onerous.

Comment: Maybe you have not paid attention to the hundreds of times I have mentioned oregon has 26 pages of amendments the WAC or Washington administrative code is quite similar. As I said if their is a breaker at the service this could be done without that knowledge it is a long and possibly wrong answer.

Comment: @EdBeal Yes, but here I'm not claiming a meter-main is *required* for OP.  I'm claiming it would turn that service wire into a feeder, so the pipe could be shared.  I happen to think meter-mains are useful, and I recommend them in many cases where they are not required.

Comment: @George you are right, I am making it harder than it is :) Edited.

Comment: Thanks @Harper-ReinstateMonica

Answer (score -2):

It all depends where your service disconnect overprotection is located.

Your panel looks like a MLO if the photo went down ~4” lower I could say yes or no.

If your service disconnect is at the meter and there is a main breaker the answer is YES you can use the same pipe if large enough to allow the wire fill.

Comment: My view of it is it's clearly a recent panel because of the terminal covers (so not Rule of Six/split bus), and I see a plastic pipe and no ground wire, so it can't be fed from a main elsewhere.

Comment: Terminal covers have been around for close to 20 years longer in some brands. With the 99 code or before the ground was not required in the pipe with the feeder

Comment: Even with the edit , wrong again, the op said this is the main with a 100 amp breaker the wire only has to be 83 amp! So aluminum 2 is fine again!

Comment: That only works if the service is 100A.  Those main wires are too large to be #4 copper.  That is a 150-200A service.